# Save Subset of MongoDB Collection to Another Collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a set like so

```
{date: 20120101}
{date: 20120103}
{date: 20120104}
{date: 20120005}
{date: 20120105}
```

How do I save a subset of those documents with the date '20120105' to another collection?

**i.e** `db.subset.save(db.full_set.find({date: "20120105"}));`

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Here's the shell version:

```
db.full_set.find({date:"20120105"}).forEach(function(doc){
   db.subset.insert(doc);
});
```

Note: As of MongoDB 2.6, the aggregation framework makes it possible to do this faster; see [melan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25247084/1448678) for details.

Comment: As of [2.2](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/), insert can take an array of docs, so you could do `var docs = ...find(...).toArray(); db.coll.insert(docs)`. I haven't found performance to be very good in either case, though

Comment: Unfortunately [$out](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) came to Mongo since version [2.6](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6/), not [2.2](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.2/)

Answer (score 106):

I would advise using the aggregation framework:

```
db.full_set.aggregate([ { $match: { date: "20120105" } }, { $out: "subset" } ])
```

It works about 100 times faster than `forEach` at least in my case. This is because the entire aggregation pipeline runs in the mongod process, whereas a solution based on `find()` and `insert()` has to send all of the documents from the server to the client and then back. This has a performance penalty, even if the server and client are on the same machine.

Comment: just take in account that it will fail if aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)

Comment: $out doesn't have the usual limitation on document size, since you're writing to a collection

Comment: Further evidence: I just ran a comparison with my own data and aggregate is about 50x faster than forEach.  I also compared to mapreduce, and aggregate is about 5x faster.

Comment: Warning. This is a very dangerous command. It will remove anything that is on the "subset" collection.

Comment: To clarify the comment by @zhaokongsheng,  if the `$out` collection already exists "... the `$out` stage atomically replaces the existing collection with the new results collection." `$out` does not append to the existing collection.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/

Comment: do see if you guys find something to implement from https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12280 
Also, $merge is another https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/ and even shows the comparison with $out but when I try use it after $match, i get the error MongoError: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$merge'

Answer (score 21):

The most general solution is this:

Make use of the aggregation (answer given by @melan):

```
db.full_set.aggregate({$match:{your query here...}},{$out:"sample"})
db.sample.copyTo("subset")
```

This works even when there are documents in "subset" before the operation and you want to preserve those "old" documents and just insert a new subset into it.

Care must be taken, because the `copyTo()` command replaces the documents with the same `_id`.

Comment: The explanation of copyTo was very useful addition.

Answer (score 20):

Actually, there is an equivalent of SQL's `insert into ... select from` in MongoDB. First, you convert multiple documents into an array of documents; then you insert the array into the target collection

```
db.subset.insert(db.full_set.find({date:"20120105"}).toArray())
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no direct equivalent of SQL's `insert into ... select from ...`.

You have to take care of it yourself. Fetch documents of interest and save them to another collection.

You can do it in the shell, but I'd use a small external script in Ruby. Something like this:

```
require 'mongo'

db = Mongo::Connection.new.db('mydb')

source = db.collection('source_collection')
target = db.collection('target_collection')

source.find(date: "20120105").each do |doc|
  target.insert doc
end
```

Comment: This bring each document to the client, while [aggregation runs entirely on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711529/save-subset-of-mongodb-collection-to-another-collection/25247084#25247084).

Comment: @DanDascalescu: note the timestamp of the answer. At that time there was no aggregation framework.

Comment: Good to see you're still active on SO! Would be nice to update the answer now that it's been a while and there are better solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Mongodb has aggregate along with $out operator which allow to save subset into new collection. Following are the details :

**$out** Takes the documents returned by the aggregation pipeline and writes them to a specified collection.

- The $out operation creates a new collection in the current database if one does not already exist.
- The collection is not visible until the aggregation completes.
- If the aggregation fails, MongoDB does not create the collection.

Syntax :

```
{ $out: "<output-collection>" }
```

**Example** 
A collection books contains the following documents:

```
{ "_id" : 8751, "title" : "The Banquet", "author" : "Dante", "copies" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 8752, "title" : "Divine Comedy", "author" : "Dante", "copies" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 8645, "title" : "Eclogues", "author" : "Dante", "copies" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 7000, "title" : "The Odyssey", "author" : "Homer", "copies" : 10 }
{ "_id" : 7020, "title" : "Iliad", "author" : "Homer", "copies" : 10 }
```

The following aggregation operation pivots the data in the books collection to have titles grouped by authors and then writes the results to the authors collection.

```
db.books.aggregate( [
  { $group : { _id : "$author", books: { $push: "$title" } } },
    { $out : "authors" }
] )
```

After the operation, the authors collection contains the following documents:

```
{ "_id" : "Homer", "books" : [ "The Odyssey", "Iliad" ] }
{ "_id" : "Dante", "books" : [ "The Banquet", "Divine Comedy", "Eclogues" ] }
```

In the asked question, use following query and you will get new collection named 'col_20120105' in your database

```
 db.products.aggregate([
  { $match : { date : "20120105" } },
  { $out : "col_20120105" }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use $merge aggregation pipeline stage.

```
db.full_set.aggregate([
  {$match: {...}},
  { $merge: {
     into: { db: 'your_db', coll: 'your_another_collection' },
     on: '_id',
     whenMatched: 'keepExisting',
     whenNotMatched: 'insert'
  }}
])
```