# Mongodb Find and Upsert

Tags: mongodb

I want to upsert the result of a find() query into another collection.

Currently  I do it this way:

```
db.source_collection.find(
    { <my filters> },
    { <my columns> }
).forEach(function (doc) {
    db.target_collection.update(
        { <my key > },
        { <my fields to upsert> }
        { multie : true, upsert: true }
    )
})
```

Is there faster way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711529/save-subset-of-mongodb-collection-to-another-collection

Comment: The $out is much faster but it will create or replace the collection. I look for a way to do an upsert