# Filter out fields from collection document and store it in new collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have following collection document

```
 {

            "Dine" : {
                    "Cuisine" : "North Indian",
                    "Popular Dishes" : "Aaloo Tikki, Pao Bhaji, Bhalla Papdi",
                    "Dine In Available" : "Yes",
                    "Online Booking" : "",
                    "Home Delivery" : "",
                    "Pure Veg" : "Yes",
                    "Restaurant Type" : "",
                    "Air Conditioned" : "",
                    "Outdoor Area" : "",
                    "Pint of Beer" : "",
                    "Bar Available" : "",
                    "Wifi" : "",
                    "Number of Deals" : "",
                    "Happy Hours" : "",
                    "Cost for 2" : "Rs 0-250",
                    "Credit Cards Accepted" : "",
                    "Deal Available" : ""
            },
            "Location Details" : {


                    "Latitude" : "28.7004740",
                    "Longitude" : "77.1174010",

            },
            "MetaData" : {
                    "Meta Description" : "",
                    "Meta Keywords" : ""
            },
            "Operation Hours" : {
                    "Operation Hours" : "11 AM-11 PM"
            },
            "Other Options" : {
                    "Chain Name" : "",
                    "Expiry Date" : "",
                    "As seen in" : "",
                    "Deals Head" : "",
                    "Deals ID" : "",
                    "Events Head" : "",
                    "Events ID" : "",
                    "Show Bookings" : "",
                    "Form Reciever Email" : "",
                    "Powered By" : "",
                    "Show Photos" : ""
            },
            "__v" : 0,
            "_id" : "-bittoo"
    }
```

I want to make a document like:

```
  {
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]
  }
}
```

where **type:** `Feature` and **geometry.type:** `Point` are written by default.Also the coordinates are latitude and longitude from"Location Details",further I want to store these generated result to get stored in another collection.

Comment: Hi Aditya - can you explain what transformation you want to use, to convert those latitude and longitude numbers to those co-ordinate numbers?

Comment: Try the answers in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711529/save-subset-of-mongodb-collection-to-another-collection

Answer (score 0):

This below query and javascript function will help you in creating a new document as per your expectation.

Execute the query in mongo shell

```
db.yourcollectionname.find().forEach(function(doc){
   var array = [doc.LocationDetails.Latitude, doc.LocationDetails.Longitude];
   var geometry = { "type" : "point",  "coordinates" : array};
   var newDoc = {};
   newDoc["type"] = "Feature";
   newDoc["geometry"] = geometry;

   db.yournewcollectionname.insert(newDoc);
});
```

You can do a find after executing the above query

`db.yournewcollectionname.find()` and see the desired documents in the new collection.

A sample output

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("57bee0cbc9735bf0b80c23e0"),
        "type" : "Feature",
        "geometry" : {
                "type" : "point",
                "coordinates" : [
                        "28.7004740",
                        "77.1174010"
                ]
        }
}
```

Note: I have removed the space in `"Location Details"` and had it as `"LocationDetails"` for arriving at the query. It would be easier to process key names without spaces and it is also a good practice.

An alternative approach to this is we can use `$aggregate` and `$out` together to acheive the same result.

Refer this post for more info [Save Subset of MongoDB Collection to Another Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711529/save-subset-of-mongodb-collection-to-another-collection)

Hope it Helps!