# Mongodb shell asking for more lines in query

Tags: mongodb

I have this query and for some reason when I enter it into the shell in cmd on windows its asking me for more lines?

```
> db.options.aggregate([{$match: {Update_Date: {$gte: "20180201" } }, { $out: "options_2" } ])
...
...
>
```

Got the query from here, [Save Subset of MongoDB Collection to Another Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711529/save-subset-of-mongodb-collection-to-another-collection), trying to not use the multi-line answer.

Comment: You're missing a closing brace in the `$match` pipeline details. Looks like a typo.

Comment: Ugh. Thanks. (This comment must be 15 characters in length)

Comment: `db.options.aggregate([{ $match: { Update_Date: { $gte: "20180201" } }}, { $out: "options_2" } ])` You really should get a modern text editor with linting. Also the `$gte` accepts a "value" and not an "object".

Comment: Yea I use atom I was just being dumb and started notepad, my bad.