# MongoDB: How To Save Returned Results To Another Collection?

Tags: mongodb

**Consider the following:**

I have a MongoDB collection named `C_a`. It contains a very large number of documents (e.g., more than 50,000,000).

For the sake of simplicity let's assume that each document has the following schema:

```
{
    "username" : "Aventinus"
    "text": "I love StackOverflow!",
    "tags": [
      "programming",
      "mongodb"
    ]
}
```

Using text index I can return all documents which contain the keyword `StackOverflow` like this:

```
db.C_a.find({$text:{$search:"StackOverflow"}})
```

**My question is the following:**

Considering that the query above may return hundreds of thousands of documents, what is the easiest/fastest way to directly save the returned results into another collection named `C_b`?

Note: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25247084/873309) post explains how to use `aggregate` to find *exact* matches (i.e., specific dates). I'm interested in using [Text Index](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_text_search.htm) to save all the posts which include a ***specific*** keyword.

Answer (score 1):

The referenced answer is correct. The example query from that answer can be updated to use your criteria:

```
db.C_a.aggregate([
  {$match: {$text: {$search:"StackOverflow"}}},
  {$out:"C_b"}
]);
```

From the MongoDB documentation for [`$text`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/index.html):

> If using the $text operator in aggregation, the following restrictions also apply.
>
> - The $match stage that includes a $text must be the first stage in the pipeline.
> - A text operator can only occur once in the stage.
> - The text operator expression cannot appear in $or or $not expressions.
> - The text search, by default, does not return the matching documents in order of matching scores. Use the $meta aggregation expression in the $sort stage.